# Padding between nodes in cytoscape.js

Tags: cytoscape.js

Created a graph using cytoscape.js in hierarchical structure. I am placing some charts and labels near each node at right position of the node but it is overlapping the nearer node in hierarchical structure. Is there any way to make space between nodes?

[image]

Comment: What did you try? Show the code.

Comment: You can see the structure at:    https://github.com/cytoscape/cytoscape.js/issues/803

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/naL1byg8/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can play with the [layout](http://js.cytoscape.org/#layouts) options.  If that is insufficient, then please [file a feature request](https://github.com/cytoscape/cytoscape.js/issues/new) if you want to request new features or options.

Comment: can we make use of rows and columns in the    layout option.

Comment: Thanks @maxkfranz. Used    layout{ name: 'dagre', nodeSep: 50 }

Answer (score 1):

Use `nodeSep` property in your `layout` options
For example:

```
var cy = window.cy = cytoscape({
        container: document.getElementById('cy'),

        layout: {
          stop: function () {
            cy.automove({
              nodesMatching: cy.$(':parent *'),
              reposition: 'drag',
              dragWith: cy.$(':parent *')
            });
          },
          name: 'cose-bilkent',
          animate: 'end',
          nodeSep: 20, // >>>>>>YOUR TARGET PROPERTY<<<<<<<
          animationEasing: 'ease-out',
          animationDuration: 2000
        }});
```